# java - making object in nested classes case

Tags: java, class, nested

I've looked all around and it seems I have the proper syntax:

```
QueueOfChars queue = new QueueOfChars();
QueueOfChars.QueueOfCharsNode charNode = queue.new QueueOfCharsNode();
```

However I get a compiling error with the charNode object I try to create

> Driver3.java:22: error: constructor QueueOfCharsNode in class
>   QueueOfChars.QueueOfCharsNode cannot be applied to given types;
>            QueueOfChars.QueueOfCharsNode charNode = queue.new QueueOfCharsNode();
>
> required: char
>    found: no arguments
>    reason: actual
>   and formal argument lists differ in length
>  1 error

It's getting this error because I have a QueueOfCharsNode(char ch)

```
public class QueueOfChars{

      public class QueueOfCharsNode{
         QueueOfCharsNode next;
         QueueOfCharsNode prev;
         char c;

         public QueueOfCharsNode(char ch){ //line causing the error
            c = ch; 
            next = prev = null;
         }
```

How do I get it to just read the "public class QueueOfCharsNode" line when I'm making the object for it?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a no-arg constructor.

You need a constructor declaration as follows:

```
public QueueOfCharsNode() { }
```

in your `QueueOfCharsNode` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
QueueOfChars.QueueOfCharsNode charNode = queue.new QueueOfCharsNode();
```

your inner class QueueOfCharsNode expects char asan argument in its constructor.
try

```
QueueOfChars.QueueOfCharsNode charNode = queue.new QueueOfCharsNode('c');//some character that you wanna pass
```

or create a no-args constructor in your inner class like.

```
public UueueOfCharsNode() {

}

QueueOfChars.QueueOfCharsNode charNode = queue.new QueueOfCharsNode();
```

would work in this case